# basis coefficient of a separable Hilbert space is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am a freshman in topology and have a question, and please help me. Thank you.

Suppose $V$ is a separable Hilbert space; it is then second countable and we can define a countable basis $\{v_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ for $V$.
For any $u\in V$, let us define

\begin{align}
u_p = \sum_{i = 1}^p <u, v_i>v_i.
\end{align}

Denote $c_u^p = [<u, v_1>, ..., <u, v_p>]^T$ and $D_p = \{c_u^p, u\in V\}$. Is $D_p$ a compact space (I am not sure if the argument is right)?

Thoughts: $D_p$ is finite-dimensional, then proving $D_p$ is bounded and closed is enough to prove the compactness. How can I prove this?

Comment: It is never bounded, hence not compact even in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: Use `\langle u,v\rangle` to get $\langle u,v\rangle$ with proper angle brackets and spacing.

Comment: $D_p=\Bbb R^p$ is not compact. (Incidentally, your definition of $u_p$ is useless.)